# Loop through files and apply function in Python

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess

I have some `dxf` files and want to transform them to `geojson` files:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import call
import os

working_directory = 'D:/dxf_files/'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(working_directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.dxf'):
            print(file)
```

Output:

```
BJ-SZZDS-1010084246-dongta-11.dxf
BJ-SZZDS-1010084246-dongta-12.dxf
BJ-SZZDS-1010084246-dongta-17.dxf
BJ-SZZDS-1010084246-dongta-18.dxf
BJ-SZZDS-1010084246-dongta-19.dxf
...
```

I want put each of these files in `input_file` below, keep `output_file` files name same as `input_file` by replacing files' extension. Now two block of code is seperated, how can I combine them together? Thanks for any help at advance.

```
input_file = 'BJ-SZZDS-1010084246-dongta-11.dxf'
output_file = 'BJ-SZZDS-1010084246-dongta-11.geojson'

def dxf2geojson(output_file, input_file):
    command = ['ogr2ogr', '-f', 'GeoJSON', output_file, input_file]
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return p
dxf2geojson(output_file, input_file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can save all filenames in a list, for example, `file_list`:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import call
import os

working_directory = 'D:/dxf_files/'

file_list = []   # define file_list to save all dxf files
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(working_directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.dxf'):
            file_list.append(file)   # save the filenames in file_list
```

Then, execute each file from the `file_list`:

```
def dxf2geojson(output_file, input_file):
    command = ['ogr2ogr', '-f', 'GeoJSON', output_file, input_file]
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return p

for input_file in file_list:
    f = input_file[:-4]  # to omit .dxf
    output_file = f + '.geojson'    # add file extension .geojson
    dxf2geojson(output_file, input_file)
```

Comment: Great. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can save all the files to a list and then iterate over it.

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import call
import os

working_directory = 'D:/dxf_files/'
def_list = []

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(working_directory):
  for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.dxf'):
      dxf_list.append(file)


def dxf2geojson(output_file, input_file):
  command = ['ogr2ogr', '-f', 'GeoJSON', output_file, input_file]
  p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  return p


for  dex_file in dexf_list:
  output_file = dex_file[:-4] + '.geojson'
  dxf2geojson(output_file, dex_file)
```

Comment: NameError: name 'input_file' is not defined. I think you missed the part to define `input_file` and `output_file`.

Comment: I fixed that. I just had to replace the `input_file` with `dex_file`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by replacing your print function in file iteration code to conversion function.

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import call
import os

working_directory = 'D:/dxf_files/'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(working_directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.dxf'):
            input_file = file
            output_file = file[:-3]+'geojson'
            P = dxf2geojson(output_file, input_file)
```